# Can't find sprint button?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the sprint button in Minecraft 1.5.2?
I know it's a silly question to ask, but I can't seem to find it. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: iirc, 1.5 didn't have a sprint button, I think you need to press your forward key (w by default) twice in rapid succession.

Comment: also can you tell me how to get jar files, cause i'm having some problem with it, thanks in advance.

Comment: @PigDestroyer - Please ask that as a seperate question... And what .jar files?

Answer (score 7):

Quickly double tap then hold the forward key (default is <kbd>W</kbd>) to sprint.
Alternatively, in version 1.7.2 or later, you can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> instead of double tapping it.

You cannot sprint if your hunger bar is 6 units (3 drumsticks [image: Drumstick][image: Drumstick][image: Drumstick]) or lower.

Comment: You mean your **Hunger** bar?

Answer (score -1):

In Minecraft **1.5.2** there's such no *sprint* key, but there's another way to sprint.
Quickly press , quickly release it, and then hold it to sprint. At the beginning it could be a bit hard, but after some days it will become easy to do.