# Why isn't my sprint key working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On the PC with version 1.8.4, I go to settings and change my sprint to <kbd>f</kbd>.

But when I hit <kbd>f</kbd>, nothing happens. I've tried other letters but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried double tapping forward (default W) with the second tap holding the key down. i don't know about the latest update but if i wanted to sprint i always had to double tap forward

Comment: @Memor-X A sprint key was added a while ago so that the double-tap isn't necessary. But, if the double-tap doesn't work *either*, that's useful data.

Comment: Are you holding the direction you want to sprint in? For example, you still need to be moving in a direction by holding a direction key (W for example).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find sprint button?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214570/cant-find-sprint-button)

Comment: What version are you using? 1.0.0? Beta 1.8? Alpha 1.2? Release 1.8?

Comment: @aytimothy: "The new update" can (and should) be assumed to be 1.8.4 until we are told otherwise. Just because we like clearly stated problems on SE does not mean we are forbidden from using our brain. It is also definitely not a duplicate of that quesiton, which is about finding the sprint key in versions without a sprint key.

Comment: Here's a thought. Does it overlap any other actions you have bound to the F key?

Comment: @crayzeedude That's a good point- isn't the f the default command for the fog distance?

Comment: @Studoku I don't think so. To be honest, I didn't think there has ever been a key that serves this function in vanilla.

Comment: @EnrangedTanker The "F" key was once a functional key back in Minecraft Beta versions, which would toggle fog distance. However at some point (most likely either Beta 1.8 or Official release 1.0), the "F" key had lost it's functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tap or hold the sprint button while holding a direction, releasing all direction keys will stop even if you continue to hold the sprint key. Simply pressing or holding the sprint button on its own will have no effect on your game.

A common layout is to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key as sprint (depending on your crouch key), so you can hold it while using the WASD keys to move.

If this is what you're doing, make sure you're saving your settings after modifying them. It's possible you're making changes and then discarding them accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably low on hunger. Eat then try double tapping the <kbd>W</kbd> key and holding it after.